# Oracle public server

Tags: database, oracle

I want to learn about oracle, to try some queries and other SQL features of oracle data base, but don't want to install and mess with all realted issues. So my question is - is there any publicly available oracle server, to which I can connect through terminal and play with it?

I mean a service where I can register and some space would be allocated to my profile

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at:  http://apex.oracle.com/

Comment: Hi Alessandro, I registered on apex, and created my schema MY_PLAYGROUND, how can I connect through terminal to that schema? Thx in advance

Comment: I don't think you can directly connect to the instance. But through the SQL Workshop (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23903_01/doc/doc.41/e21677/obj_brows.htm) you can launch commands, run scripts, etc. That's how close you can get, AFAIK, without having to install Oracle.

Answer (score 5):

The only thing I can think of is SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/

But it won't let you have a "private" space. You need to re-create your schema each time (but you can bookmark your script which might be enough for you).

Answer (score 2):

You could also try one of the pre-built virtual appliances - see

```
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/community/developer-vm/index.html
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need direct database access, you can run it in a Docker instance:

```
docker run -d -p 1521:1521 -p 8080:8080 alexeiled/docker-oracle-xe-11g
```

Then connect to it with `sqlplus`

```
sqlplus system/oracle@localhost:1521/xe
```

See [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/alexeiled/docker-oracle-xe-11g/) for more passwords, info on apex, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Just came across this: [Oracle Live SQL](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/index.html). It is browser based so nothing to install locally. But, you need to have an Oracle account.

> Browser based SQL worksheet access to an Oracle database schema